# Como apagar imagem do GridView?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, gridview

Estou desenvolvendo um app que contem uma galeria, onde o usuário tira fotos e a imagem é mostrada no `GridView`, porem não sei como fazer pra apagar a imagem selecionada

Consegui fazer algo do tipo: o usuário pressiona a imagem e aparece o ícone de uma lixeirinha de apagar mas não apaga.

Segue meu código:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ActionMode;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class GaleriaaSp extends AppCompatActivity {

    FloatingActionButton fab_plus,fab_twitterr,fab_fb;
    Animation FabOpen,FabClose,FabRClockwise,FabRantiClockwise;
    boolean isOpen=false;
    final int CAMERA_GALERIA =12;
    FloatingActionButton captureBtn = null;
    final int CAMERA_CAPTURE = 1;
    private Uri picUri;
    private DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    private GridView grid;
    private List <String> listOfImagesPath;
    private ArrayList <String> list;

     int count=0;

    public static final String GridViewDemo_ImagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/GridViewDemo/";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_galeriaa_sp);


        fab_plus =(FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab_plus);
        fab_twitterr =(FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab_camera);
        fab_fb =(FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab_galeria);
        FabOpen = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fab_open);
        FabClose = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.fab_close);
        FabRClockwise = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.rotate_clockwise);
        FabRantiClockwise = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.rotate_anticlockwise);

         grid = ( GridView) findViewById(R.id.GridView);

        listOfImagesPath = null;
        listOfImagesPath = RetriveCapturedImagePath();
        if(listOfImagesPath!=null){
        grid.setAdapter(new ImageListAdapter(this,listOfImagesPath));
        }


              //      CHAAMAR CAMERA twitterr
        fab_twitterr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                 Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                 startActivityForResult(captureIntent, CAMERA_CAPTURE);


                fab_fb.startAnimation(FabClose);
                fab_twitterr.startAnimation(FabClose);
                fab_plus.startAnimation(FabRantiClockwise);
                fab_twitterr.setClickable(false);
                fab_fb.setClickable(false);
                isOpen = false;
            }
        });



        //      CHAAMAR Galeria twitter

        fab_fb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                Intent intent = new Intent();
               intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Selecione uma imagem"), CAMERA_GALERIA);

                fab_fb.startAnimation(FabClose);
                fab_twitterr.startAnimation(FabClose);
                fab_plus.startAnimation(FabRantiClockwise);
                fab_twitterr.setClickable(false);
                fab_fb.setClickable(false);
                isOpen = false;
            }
        });



        fab_plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                if (isOpen) {

                    fab_fb.startAnimation(FabClose);
                    fab_twitterr.startAnimation(FabClose);
                    fab_plus.startAnimation(FabRantiClockwise);
                    fab_twitterr.setClickable(false);
                    fab_fb.setClickable(false);
                    isOpen = false;

                } else {

                    fab_fb.startAnimation(FabOpen);
                    fab_twitterr.startAnimation(FabOpen);
                    fab_plus.startAnimation(FabRClockwise);
                    fab_twitterr.setClickable(true);
                    fab_fb.setClickable(true);
                    isOpen = true;


                }


            }
        });



        grid.setChoiceMode(GridView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
        grid.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {


                count = count + 1;
                mode.setTitle(count + " items selecionado");
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode arg0, Menu arg1) {

                MenuInflater inflater = arg0.getMenuInflater();
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.munu_delete, arg1);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode arg0, Menu arg1) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode arg0, MenuItem arg1) {


                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode arg1) {

            }
        });



        grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {


                String imagem = listOfImagesPath.get(position).toString();
                Intent i = new Intent(GaleriaaSp.this, Zomgaleria.class);//mude aqui de acordo com a sua activity
                i.putExtra("img", imagem);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    //    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_galeriaa_sp, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        /// RECEBIMENTO DA CAMERA
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
             if(requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE){
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                Bitmap thePic = extras.getParcelable("data");
                String imgcurTime = dateFormat.format(new Date());
                File imageDirectory = new File(GridViewDemo_ImagePath);
                imageDirectory.mkdirs();
                String _path = GridViewDemo_ImagePath + imgcurTime+".jpg";
                try {
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(_path);
                    thePic.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
                    out.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.getMessage();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                listOfImagesPath = null;
                listOfImagesPath = RetriveCapturedImagePath();
                if(listOfImagesPath!=null){
                    grid.setAdapter(new ImageListAdapter(this,listOfImagesPath));
                }
            }
        }



        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if(requestCode == CAMERA_GALERIA){
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                Bitmap thePic = extras.getParcelable("data");
                String imgcurTime = dateFormat.format(new Date());
                File imageDirectory = new File(GridViewDemo_ImagePath);
                imageDirectory.mkdirs();
                String _path = GridViewDemo_ImagePath + imgcurTime+".jpg";
                try {
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(_path);
                    thePic.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
                    out.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.getMessage();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                listOfImagesPath = null;
                listOfImagesPath = RetriveCapturedImagePath();
                if(listOfImagesPath!=null){
                    grid.setAdapter(new ImageListAdapter(this,listOfImagesPath));
                }
            }
        }


            /// RECEBIMENTO DA GALERIA
    }

    private List<String> RetriveCapturedImagePath() {
        List<String> tFileList = new ArrayList<String>();
        File f = new File(GridViewDemo_ImagePath);
        if (f.exists()) {
            File[] files=f.listFiles();
            Arrays.sort(files);

            for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++){
                File file = files[i];
                if(file.isDirectory())
                    continue;
                tFileList.add(file.getPath());
            }
        }
        return tFileList;
    }



    public class ImageListAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        private Context context;
        private List<String> imgPic;
        public ImageListAdapter(Context c, List<String> thePic)
        {
            context = c;
            imgPic = thePic;
        }
        public int getCount() {
            if(imgPic != null)
                return imgPic.size();
            else
                return 0;
        }




        //---returns the ID of an item---
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        //---returns an ImageView view---
        public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            final ImageView imageView;
            BitmapFactory.Options bfOptions=new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bfOptions.inDither=false;                     //Disable Dithering mode
            bfOptions.inPurgeable=true;                   //Tell to gc that whether it needs free memory, the Bitmap can be cleared
            bfOptions.inInputShareable=true;             //Which kind of reference will be used to recover the Bitmap data after being clear, when it will be used in the future
            bfOptions.inTempStorage=new byte[32 * 1024];
            if (convertView == null) {
                imageView = new ImageView(context);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                imageView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
            } else {
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }
            FileInputStream fs = null;
            final Bitmap bm;
            try {
                fs = new FileInputStream(new File(imgPic.get(position).toString()));

                if(fs!=null) {



                    bm=BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fs.getFD(), null, bfOptions);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
                    imageView.setId(position);
                    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(360, 370));

              /* imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v){

                        //   imgPic.remove(position).toString();
//String bm = null;

                            //String imagem = imgPic.get(position).toString();
                            //Intent i = new Intent(GaleriaSp.this, Zomgaleria.class);//mude aqui de acordo com a sua activity
                            //i.putExtra("img", imagem);
                            //startActivity(i);
                        }

                    });*/


                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally{
                if(fs!=null) {
                    try {
                        fs.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            return imageView;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dentro do `setMultiChoiceModeListener` crie a variável para pegar a posição no momento em que selecionar do `int`, por exemplo:

```
int position =0;
```

No método `onActionItemClicked` você pode usar o `listOfImagesPath.get(position)` para pegar o endereço onde a imagem está localizada. Então use o `file.delete()` para apagar do dispositivo. Agora para sumir da tela, você precisa remover o item da sua lista desta forma `listOfImagesPath.remove(position)`. Resultado:

```
@Override
public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode arg0, MenuItem arg1) {

    int id = arg1.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_delete) {

        File file = new File(listOfImagesPath.get(position));
        file.delete();

        listOfImagesPath.remove(position);
        arg0.finish();

        return true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Boa Sorte!

Comment: Cara muito obg de coração muito bem explicado , salvou minha vidaaa parabens obg